# UART problem on STR912FAW

Tags: arm, uart

My code is here:

```
#include <91x_lib.h>
UART_InitTypeDef UART_InitStructure;
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;

void SCU_Configuration(void);
void GPIO_Configuration(void);


u8 i;
u8 name[]="ABCDE";
u8 c;

main()
{
    c=0; i=5;
    SCU_Configuration();
    GPIO_Configuration();
    UART_DeInit(UART0);
    UART_InitStructure.UART_WordLength = UART_WordLength_8D;
    UART_InitStructure.UART_StopBits = UART_StopBits_1;
    UART_InitStructure.UART_Parity = UART_Parity_No ;
    UART_InitStructure.UART_BaudRate = 9600;
    UART_InitStructure.UART_HardwareFlowControl = UART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
    UART_InitStructure.UART_Mode = UART_Mode_Tx;
    UART_InitStructure.UART_FIFO = UART_FIFO_Disable;
    //UART_InitStructure.UART_TxFIFOLevel = UART_FIFOLevel_1_2;
    //UART_InitStructure.UART_RxFIFOLevel = UART_FIFOLevel_1_2;


    UART_Init(UART0, &UART_InitStructure);

    UART_ITConfig(UART0, UART_IT_Receive    , DISABLE);
    UART_ITConfig(UART0, UART_IT_Transmit   , DISABLE);

    UART_Cmd(UART0, ENABLE);

    while(i--)
    {
        UART_SendData(UART0, name[c++]);
        while(UART_GetFlagStatus(UART0, UART_FLAG_TxFIFOFull) != RESET);
    }       
}



void SCU_Configuration(void)
{
    SCU_MCLKSourceConfig(SCU_MCLK_OSC);
    SCU_PLLFactorsConfig(192, 25, 2);
    SCU_PLLCmd(ENABLE);
    SCU_RCLKDivisorConfig(SCU_RCLK_Div1); /* RCLK @96Mhz */
    SCU_HCLKDivisorConfig(SCU_HCLK_Div1); /* AHB @96Mhz */
    SCU_FMICLKDivisorConfig(SCU_FMICLK_Div1);/* FMI @96Mhz */
    SCU_PCLKDivisorConfig(SCU_PCLK_Div2); /* APB @48Mhz */
    SCU_MCLKSourceConfig(SCU_MCLK_PLL);  /* MCLK @96Mhz */
    SCU_BRCLKDivisorConfig(SCU_BRCLK_Div2 );

    SCU_APBPeriphClockConfig(__UART0, ENABLE);
    SCU_APBPeriphClockConfig(__GPIO3, ENABLE);
}

void GPIO_Configuration(void)
{
    GPIO_DeInit(GPIO3);

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Direction = GPIO_PinOutput;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_1;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Type = GPIO_Type_OpenCollector ;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Alternate = GPIO_OutputAlt3  ;
    GPIO_Init (GPIO3, &GPIO_InitStructure);     

    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Direction = GPIO_PinInput;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_IPInputConnected = GPIO_IPInputConnected_Enable;
    GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Alternate = GPIO_InputAlt1  ;
    GPIO_Init (GPIO3, &GPIO_InitStructure);
}
```

I thought that I did everthing right but I couldn't see on serial window. 
I use MCBSTR9 board.
why?

Comment: Could you please indent your code and put in some comments? Have you checked the serial lines with an oscilloscope to see if they wiggle?

Comment: I did. they werent wiggle. i dont know why?  i load to board example uart program that is running but my program dont run.

Comment: I don't remember for the STR9 off-hand, but does the `SCU` also have reset registers for peripherals that you need to disable?

Answer (score 1):

You could try some/all of these:

- Enabling the FIFO and uncommenting these lines like this:

  ```
  UART_InitStructure.UART_FIFO = UART_FIFO_Enable;
  UART_InitStructure.UART_TxFIFOLevel = UART_FIFOLevel_1_2;
  UART_InitStructure.UART_RxFIFOLevel = UART_FIFOLevel_1_2;
  ```
- Also make the TX pin push-pull instead

  ```
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Type = GPIO_Type_PushPull;
  ```
- Try these clock settings for 48 Mhz

  ```
  SCU_PLLFactorsConfig(192, 25, 3); 

  SCU_PLLCmd(ENABLE); 
  SCU_RCLKDivisorConfig(SCU_RCLK_Div1); 
  SCU_HCLKDivisorConfig(SCU_HCLK_Div1); 
  SCU_PCLKDivisorConfig(SCU_PCLK_Div2); 
  SCU_FMICLKDivisorConfig(SCU_FMICLK_Div1); 
  SCU_MCLKSourceConfig(SCU_MCLK_PLL);
  ```